# Atom - Emmet package: closing comments

Tags: html, comments, sublimetext3, atom-editor, emmet

**Emmet for Atom: Auto comments after html closing tag.**

I can't seem to find a solution to this problem anywhere so I've resorted to asking on here.

http://iaintnoextra.tumblr.com/post/68089741466/automatically-add-closing-comments-to-html-using

In Sublime Text 3, using the emmet user preferences file from the link above, emmet automatically adds comments after a closing html tag; for example:

```
div.container
```

would produce:

```
<div class="container"></div><!-- /.container -->
```

I can't seem to find anywhere within Emmet's package settings to make this happen on Atom V1. Does anyone know where I can change this so it mimics the same functionality?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://www.devstavern.com/emmet/custom-comments-in-emmet-sublime-atom-and-others/

With the help of the link above I managed to figure this out on my own, here's the answer:

1. Edit your emmet settings on Atom.
2. Update your extensions path under the "Settings" heading to a location where you'd like to save your preferences.json file that we'll create next, I've created a folder in my dropbox folder so I can access the file from any location.
3. Create a preferences.json file in the folder we just created, add this code below

Comment on same line:

```
{
  "filter.commentAfter": "<!-- /<%= attr('id', '#') %><%= attr('class', '.') %> -->"
}
```

Comment on new line:

```
{
  "filter.commentAfter": "\n<!-- /<%= attr('id', '#') %><%= attr('class', '.') %> -->"
}
```

4. Go to your `.atom\packages\emmet\node_modules\emmet\lib` folder and edit snippets.json.
5. Find the html snippet and change the filters setting to "html, c", this will automatically add a comment to the end of any auto-completed code which is shown above.

Ta-da, it works!

**Update (05/11/15):**

Make sure you restart Atom after saving your changes.

Comment: For step 4., I believe you can also put the snippets.json updates in the extensions path.  For example, the default would be ~/emmet/snippets.json.  This way your snippets won't get blown out if the atom package changes.

`{
    "html": {
        "filters": "html,c"
      }
}`

Comment: I created the preferences.json file (I don't want to edit snippets.json file and want to override it with preferences.json) for Atom/Emmet [like this](http://pastebin.com/ph7cDZAQ) but it does not work as I expect (for auto creating comment). Is there any way to get work this?

Answer (score 0):

i changed html.js file (tag generator) on C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Brackets\extensions\user\brackets-emmet\node_modules\emmet\lib\filter

https://gist.github.com/mgundogdu38/a53af0bccd61bba4cefac56ab705d2b1

Now:[image]

1- i find html tag generator library. html.js.
2- i find html tag generator functions. it is called processTag.
3- i need attribute generator function. it is called makeAttributesString. after i cloned. i called "makeAttributesString2"  :)

```
function makeAttributesString2(node, profile) {
    var attrQuote = profile.attributeQuote();
    var cursor = profile.cursor();

    return node.attributeList().map(function(a) {
        var isBoolean = profile.isBoolean(a.name, a.value);
        var attrName = profile.attributeName(a.name);
        var attrValue = isBoolean ? attrName : a.value;
        //i added there. if attribute is id. i added "." on head
        if(attrName == "id")
        {
            return "#"+(attrValue || cursor);
        }
  //if attribute is class i added "." on head
        if(attrName == "class")
        {
            return "."+(attrValue || cursor);
        }
        //else only tagname
        if (isBoolean && profile.allowCompactBoolean()) {
            return ' ' + attrName;
        }
  //end of my code
    }).join('');
}
```

4. then i use makeAttributesString2 for generate comment title on proccessTag.

   ```
   function processTag(item, profile) {
   if (!item.parent) { // looks like it's root element
       return item;
   }

   var attrs = makeAttributesString(item, profile); 

   var cursor = profile.cursor();
   var isUnary = abbrUtils.isUnary(item);
   var start = '';
   var end = '';

   // define opening and closing tags
   if (!item.isTextNode()) {
        //this is pieace of comment title.
       var attrsComment = makeAttributesString2(item,profile);
       var tagName = profile.tagName(item.name());
       if (isUnary) {
           start = '<' + tagName + attrs + profile.selfClosing() + '>';
           item.end = '';
       } else {
       //there is comment tag. i just add "<!-- "+tagName+attrsComment+" -->\n" and "\n <!-- /"+tagName+attrsComment+" -->"
       start = "<!-- "+tagName+attrsComment+" -->\n"+ '<' + tagName + attrs + '>';
           end = '</' + tagName + '>'+"\n <!-- /"+tagName+attrsComment+" -->";
       }
   }

   var placeholder = '%s';
   // We can't just replace placeholder with new value because
   // JavaScript will treat double $ character as a single one, assuming
   // we're using RegExp literal.
   item.start = utils.replaceSubstring(item.start, start,     item.start.indexOf(placeholder), placeholder);
   item.end = utils.replaceSubstring(item.end, end,    item.end.indexOf(placeholder), placeholder);

   // should we put caret placeholder after opening tag?
   if (
           !item.children.length 
           && !isUnary 
           && !~item.content.indexOf(cursor)
           && !tabStops.extract(item.content).tabstops.length
       ) {
       item.start += cursor;
   }

   return item;
   }
   ```

Comment: I think this could be a useful answer, but links tend to get broken over time (even if it is your gist). I'd suggest you copy-paste and explain at least the most relevant parts of your code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone wants to do this with VS Code in 2018, this is what I found to work.

```js
  "emmet.preferences": {
    "filter.commentAfter": "<!-- /[#ID][.CLASS] -->"
  },
  "emmet.syntaxProfiles": {
    "html": {
      "filters": "html, c"
    }
  }
```

Add this to your existing User Settings, and it should just work :)